# Sequentially append specific name-value pairs in json objects to a csv file

Tags: python, json

I've got the following JSON that is ordered by time:

```
{'quotes': [{'t': '2021-07-06T13:45:00.005216368Z', 'ax': 'H', 'ap': 359.52, 'as': 2, 'bx': 'U', 'bp': 359.51, 'bs': 2, 'c': ['R']}, {'t': '2021-07-06T13:45:00.00533471Z', 'ax': 'H', 'ap': 359.52, 'as': 2, 'bx': 'Q', 'bp': 359.51, 'bs': 2, 'c': ['R']}, {'t': '2021-07-06T13:45:00.005559387Z', 'ax': 'H', 'ap': 359.52, 'as': 2, 'bx': 'Q', 'bp': 359.51, 'bs': 3, 'c': ['R']}, {'t': '2021-07-06T13:45:00.006669818Z', 'ax': 'P', 'ap': 359.53, 'as': 3, 'bx': 'Q', 'bp': 359.51, 'bs': 3, 'c': ['R']}, {'t': '2021-07-06T13:45:00.008649561Z', 'ax': 'P', 'ap': 359.53, 'as': 3, 'bx': 'Q', 'bp': 359.51, 'bs': 4, 'c': ['R']}], 'code': 'Q1QQ', 'next_page_token': None}
```

I'm trying to append "t" and "bp" to a csv file and keep these name-value pairs in the same order. Using the example above, the file would look like this:

```
"t", "bp"     
2021-07-06T13:45:00.005216368Z, 359.51
2021-07-06T13:45:00.00533471Z, 359.51
2021-07-06T13:45:00.005559387Z, 359.51
2021-07-06T13:45:00.006669818Z, 359.51 
2021-07-06T13:45:00.008649561Z, 359.51
```

Here's my attempt, which works but it does seem quite slow:

```
from json import dumps, loads
from requests import get

response = dumps(get(url = 'https://***', params = {***}.json()['results'])

cycle = [0]

while cycle[-1] < len(loads(response)):
     print(loads(response)[cycle[-1]]['t'], ',', loads(response)[cycle[-1]]['bp'], file = open(file = 'specific_name_pairs.csv', mode ='a'))
     cycle.append(cycle[-1] + 1)
```

Is there a more efficient/"pythonic" way to achieve this? Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Where is `json_objects` declared? Is that another name for the data named `response`?

Comment: What does the URL actually return? Your sample seems to show a comma delimited string of JSON objects. Is that really what you expect? Also, your loop needs a complete re-write - but that can only be done once you've clarified what the input is

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've uptaded response to show the exect structure of JSON objects.

Comment: You really need to show what the URL responds with. The change you've made makes no sense unless you're suggesting that the URL responds with a string representation of a Python list (which I doubt)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - I've edited the response to be complete.

Comment: OK - Working on it. However, I find it odd that your output file has a .json extension when it's more like traditional CSV. Why is that?

Comment: @AndyKnight my mistake again, thanks for highlighting - it should be specific_name_pairs.csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need make appropriate changes to the variables TESTING, URL, PARAMS and OUTPUTFILE. Otherwise, this will do what you've asked for and I hope you find it instructive. Unlike a previous answer, I've chosen not to use the CSV module because IMO it's overkill for this simple case.

```
import requests
    
    TESTING = True
    URL = 'https://foo'
    PARAMS = {}
    OUTPUTFILE = '/Users/andy/specific_name_pairs.csv'
    SAMPLE = {'quotes': [{'t': '2021-07-06T13:45:00.005216368Z', 'ax': 'H', 'ap': 359.52, 'as': 2, 'bx': 'U', 'bp': 359.51, 'bs': 2, 'c': ['R']},
                         {'t': '2021-07-06T13:45:00.00533471Z', 'ax': 'H', 'ap': 359.52,'as': 2, 'bx': 'Q', 'bp': 359.51, 'bs': 2, 'c': ['R']},
                         {'t': '2021-07-06T13:45:00.005559387Z', 'ax': 'H', 'ap': 359.52, 'as': 2, 'bx': 'Q', 'bp': 359.51, 'bs': 3, 'c': ['R']}]}
    
    
    def getdata():
        if TESTING:
            return SAMPLE
        else:
            r = requests.get(URL, PARAMS)
            r.raise_for_status()
            return r.json()
    
    
    def process():
        data = getdata()
        with open(OUTPUTFILE, 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write('"t", "bp"\n')
            for j in data['quotes']:
                outfile.write(f'{j["t"]}, {j["bp"]}\n')
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        process()
```

Comment: Thanks @AndyKnight, this novice coder very much appreciates the help!

Answer (score 2):

[csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) provides a [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) class that can be used for serializing `dict` objects to CSV records.

A couple of issues with the code:

- the response is deserialized each time a cycle of the loop runs
- file is opened each time a cycle of the loop runs and leaves many file handles open.

You can remedy this by:

- [Deserializing JSON response content](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) before going into the loop
- Opening the file using the context manager so that the file is [properly closed after statements in the block are executed](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)
- Ensure proper serialization of objects using the csv module

```py
import csv
from requests import get

response = get(url = 'https://***', params = {***})

response_lst = response.json()
quotes =  response_lst['quotes']

with open('specific_name_pairs.json', mode='w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=['t', 'bp'])
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    for item in quotes:
        record = {'t': item['t'], 'bp': item['bp']}
        csv_writer.writerow(record)
```

Comment: Are you expecting response_lst to be iterable?

Comment: Yes. That's inferred from how OP's code indexes the serialized response content.

Comment: That's correct.  I see that the response content is actually a  JSON object data type and not a array data type.